# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'crawler'

Tags: python, web-crawler

I am doing a fake news detection as a college project and have written a crawler program for crawling a webpage for information. But when I try to import the crawler into another program it is giving an error of module not found. I am not able to understand how to resolve this issue. I have copied the error here

---

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
2 import os
3 from sklearn.utils import shuffle
----> 4 import crawler
5 LEN=2

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'crawler'

Comment: did you install the crawler? if not use `pip install crawler`

Comment: @WaveShaper Thank you so much sir, it has worked.